# ubuntu script no such file /etc/init.d/ script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, boot

i'm trying to run this script at start up but this is constantly giving me error that `/etc/init.d/put_ubuntu_users: 14: /etc/init.d/put_ubuntu_users: cannot open ~/data.txt: No such file`

This is my script

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Updates Password at Login
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: script for updating password
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO

                while IFS=: read f1 f2
                        do
                                user=$(sudo grep "$f1" /etc/shadow | cut -d':' -f 1);
                                pwd=$(sudo grep "$f1" /etc/shadow | cut -d':' -f 2);

                                        if [ -n "$user" -a "$f2" != "$pwd" ]; then
                                                #search for password, and repalce it with new one
                                                sudo sed -i 's@'$pwd'@'$f2'@' /etc/shadow
                                        fi

                done < ~/data.txt
```

i had run these set of commands

```
sudo chmod 755 put_ubuntu_users
sudo update-rc.d put_ubuntu_users defaults
sudo service put_ubuntu_users start
```

BTW, this script is working normally if i manually run it by typing `./put_ubuntu_users`

Please tell me ehat i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you it cannot find the file ~/data.txt. The reason is simple: /etc/init.d scripts are run as root, and I am pretty sure there is no file data.txt in /root, root's home. 
You can fix that by using `absolute` paths, not `relative` ones.

On the other hand, I find it difficult to understand what a redirection is doing after a `done` statement. What exactly are you meaning to do?

Comment: Thanks its work! :) actually i'm replacing password of user in /etc/shadow

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying the file data.txt (for the users home directory) can't be found/accessed.    The easiest way to fix this is to edit the last line of the script and change the ~/data.txt to /home/{username_here}/data.txt

Answer (score 1):

Services don't have home directories. So `~/data.txt` doesn't do what you think it does in that context. You need to put the file somewhere you reference with a static file name.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that there is no home folder set up for the init process user (which is normal).

At the start of your script, add `setuid myuser`, which will run the script as that user. Currently the init user doesn't have a home folder set up (a guess, otherwise it'd write to the home folder location). A surprisingly useful [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) about this.